# Putting text at the middle of an <hr>

Tags: html, css

Basically, I want to have a `hr` behind my text and my text will be in the middle of it.

Here's some sample markup:

```
<div class="test">
  <hr class="middle-line"/>
  Some Text
</div>

.test {
  text-align: center;
}

hr.middle-line {
    width: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: -1;
  }
```

Link to fiddle;  https://jsfiddle.net/hLh55t7p/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `absolute` positioning like this:

```css
.test {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative
}

hr.middle-line {
    width: 0px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: -1;
}
.test p{
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="test">
  <hr class="middle-line"/>
  <p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add negative values to the text margin in this way:

```
.test {
  text-align: center;
}

.test div {
  margin-top: -70px;
}

hr.middle-line {
  width: 0px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
  <hr class="middle-line"/>
  <div>Some Text</div>
</div>
```

Or you can use `position: absolute`.